# JQuery find checked radio buttons with variable

Tags: html, jquery, radio-button

I defined a variable "thisRadio", which is a div (dynamically created, no #id) that contains many radio buttons.
One of those radios is (maybe) checked. I want to find the checked radio button in this div and set it to false..
Unfortunately, my code is not working

Please tell me how can I call the radio button with the variable instead of a class name or id (I guess the problem is in line 2, no error in console).
Maybe one problem is that I run a code automatically when the radio button is clicked manually, and it creates problems when set it to false, but still, at the moment I just don't even enter line 3:

```
var thisRadio = $(this).parent();
$("thisRadio input[type=radio]:checked").each(function() {
  $(this).prop('checked', false);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the variable name directly in the selector. The right way would be using the `find` method to get the checked radio button inside it. Since, there will be only one checked input at a time you won't need the `.each` function. Here is an example:

```js
var thisRadio = $('#radios').parent();
thisRadio.find("input[type=radio]:checked").prop('checked', false);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="radios">
<input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="male" checked>
<label for="male">Male</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="female">
<label for="female">Female</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="other" name="gender" value="other">
<label for="other">Other</label>
</div>
```